# Is there a quantum operation to change a phase $e^{(0.q_0 q_1 q_2 q_3)}$ into $e^{(0.q_1 q_2 q_3)}$?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-fourier-transform

Given a set of four qubits, say $q_{0},q_{1},q_{2},q_{3}$ which represent a $4$-bit binary number with $q_{0}$ as the MSB. After applying QFT on these qubits the phase of $q_{0}$using the concept of binary fractions ($e^{\frac{a}{2^{n}}} = e^{0..an...a1}$) becomes:

> $Q(q_0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|0\rangle + e^{(0.q_{0}q_{1}q_{2}q_{3})}|1\rangle\big)$

**My question is**: Is there a quantum operation to change the phase of $Q(q_0)$ from $e^{(0.q_{0}q_{1}q_{2}q_{3})}$ to $e^{(0.q_{1}q_{2}q_{3})}$?

Comment: If you look at the QFT circuit you can simply apply the principle of reverseable computing and apply the reverse circuit related to the q3 rotation to undo it. This is basically just applying a very selective version of the inverse QFT (which would undo all the rotations).

Comment: Sorry for screwing up those last indices while formatting!

Comment: @JSdJ No worries.

Comment: You could implement your own modified 'QFT' algorithm that for $Q(q_0)$ has all the rotation indexes shift down by 1.

Comment: related on physics.SE by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/561544/58382

Comment: Yes, @SamPalmer. Motivation behind this question was that I first started by implementing a shifted QFT, but got down to thinking if there's a way to do a shift operation without changing the nature (matrix) of the gates of QFT such that the whole operation looks like this: 1-(QFT)->2-U(Shift)->3-(IQFT). Reason for this is I wanted to keep only the gate applied in 2nd part variable (according to the number of places one wants to shift) as opposed to shifting all the gates in QFT. I didn't give much thought to the 3rd part since the 2nd part now does not seem possible.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that such a transformation would not be unitary. Since it drops the information about bit $q_0$ altogether, it would have basis states that differ in that bit transformed into the same state, and that would not be possible to invert.

Comment: You could write the QFT of $q_0$ to an ancilla to preserve $q_0$?

Comment: Yes, something extra needs to be done, but I'm not sure what off the top of me head.

Comment: Ancilla needs to be preserved as well if it's going to take the value of q0 after measurement.

Comment: I think this would require a circular shift-type operation on all the qubits, to preserve information.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to undo the QFT applied to $|q_3\rangle$, so you would apply a $H$ gate to $Q(|q_3\rangle)$.

$HQ(|q_3\rangle) = |q_3\rangle$

or more generally for an $n$-qbit system

$HQ(|q_n\rangle) = |q_n\rangle$

If you then apply the conditional rotation (on $Q(|q_0\rangle)$ conditioned by $|q_3\rangle$) of angle $R_4^{\dagger}$:

$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & e^{-\pi i / 8}
\end{pmatrix}
$

to $q_0$ this will undo the $q_3$ rotation applied by QFT. You would then want to fix up the $|q_3\rangle$ state to put it back into QFT by applying a $H$ gate again.

--

I don't think you need to correct $|q_3\rangle$ for any phase-kickback after applying the conditional rotation to $Q(|q_0\rangle)$ as we're not applying the rotation to an eigenstate, but anyone feel free to correct me!

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I think there was a serious mistake in the question. I have corrected it now, the phase transition that I wanted to know is feasible or not is from (0.0123)  to (0.123). Similar to a left shift operator.